# How to run two separate plugins in parallel in a Gulp pipe?

Tags: stream, gulp, pipe, gulp-plugin

I'm trying to setup a Gulp task to convert `.ttf` fonts to webfont formats, by using `gulp-ttf2woff` and `gulp-ttf2woff2` plugins. The respectively convert the source fonts to `.woff` and `.woff2`.

I've come out with these two separate functions, one for each plugin:

```
function fontsW(done) {
    src(fontsSrc)
        .pipe(ttf2woff())
        .pipe(dest(fontsDist))
    done();
};

function fontsW2(done) {
    src(fontsSrc)
        .pipe(ttf2woff2())
        .pipe(dest(fontsDist))
    done();
};
```

Is it possible to condensate them in a single function, let's call it `function fonts(done) {}` that takes care of both plugins at once?

Basically, I'd like to have something like this

```
function fontsW2(done) {
    src(fontsSrc)
        .pipe(ttf2woff())
        .pipe(ttf2woff2())
        .pipe(dest(fontsDist))
    done();
};
```

where both `ttf2woff()` and `ttf2woff2()` receive the output of `src` and give their own processed files to `dest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
function fontsW(done) {
    src(fontsSrc)
        .pipe(ttf2woff())
        .pipe(dest(fontsDist))

     src(fontsSrc)
        .pipe(ttf2woff2())
        .pipe(dest(fontsDist))
    done();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a task that calls both functions in parallel:

```
gulp.task('fonts', gulp.parallel(ttf2woff, ttf2woff2));
```

You can either use this task in other tasks (e.g. call it from your `default` task), or you can call it directly from terminal:

```
gulp fonts
```

Comment: Thank you, I know that I can call multiple functions from a single task, but my question was about creating a single function on the first place